# GNOME / GTK app installed from source runs with default theme

Tags: gnome, source, gtk, theme

I've installed a GNOME / GTK application from source (GitG 0.2.5 in Linux Mint 11) - after resolving all the dependencies, I successfully ran the application.

The dependencies were also installed from source.

The problem is that the application ([as seen here](http://mariocuba.net/uploads/GNOME.png) to the far left) is not "themed" (unlike Firefox, to the right, you can clearly see the difference).

When running the application from the Terminal, the only error I get is:

```
'menu_proxy_module_load': gitg: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load

(gitg:25205): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)
```

Other than that, the application runs perfectly.

Back when I used Ubuntu, I had a similar problem (which ended up being something with root and the current user)

I can run the program without root permissions.

Any thoughts on this?

As I said, I'm running Linux Mint 11. Any help would be very appreciated.